# Convert class object into Json (with datetime field) - TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert object into JSON. Converting from JSON to object was simple. When I try to use the `dumps` method, I'm getting the error: `TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`. Is this possible to convert such class?

```
import json
import datetime
from types import SimpleNamespace


class Outcome:

    def __init__(self, name='', date=datetime.datetime.now(), price=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        self.price = float(price)

# convert from json to outcome
txt = b'{"name": "milk", "date": "2020-01-02", "price": 1.99}'
txt = txt.decode("utf-8")
x = json.loads(txt, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
o = Outcome(x.name, x.date, x.price)
print(o.name, o.date, o.price)

# convert outcome to json (how?)
o2 = json.dumps(o.__dict__)
print(o2.name, o2.date, o2.price)
```

Comment: When I Google that error message, I see a lot of relevant-looking results, from this site and others. Do any of them help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use check if the value is a date with `isinstance(v, datetime.date)`:

```py
import json
import datetime
from types import SimpleNamespace


class Outcome:
    def __init__(self, name='', date=datetime.datetime.now(), price=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        self.price = float(price)

# convert from json to outcome
txt = b'{"name": "milk", "date": "2020-01-02", "price": 1.99}'
txt = txt.decode("utf-8")
x = json.loads(txt, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
o = Outcome(x.name, x.date, x.price)
print(o.name, o.date, o.price)

# dict comprehension to check if each value is a date
o2 = json.dumps({k: v.isoformat() if isinstance(v, datetime.date) else v
                 for k, v in o.__dict__.items()})

print(o2)
```

Output:

```
milk 2020-01-02 00:00:00 1.99
{"name": "milk", "date": "2020-01-02T00:00:00", "price": 1.99}
```

You can also make an `encode()` and `decode()` method in your class to customize the saving and loading of your class to json and use that instead of the lambda fo `object_hook`